# Efficient and flexible Javascript library to query large JSON files that allows aggregation?

Tags: json, javascript, minimongo

I am dealing with large json files with deep hierarchical structure on the frontend and I want to be able to query and aggregate them efficiently,the same way I query mongoDB or redis collections.

I am aware of two libraries:

1. [Minimongo](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/minimongo)  which I'm not sure if can be used independently without using the entire Blaze/Meteor framework.
2. and [JSLINQ](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/)

any other suggestions, tricks ?

**Edit:**

there is also another library called [json:select()](http://jsonselect.org/#overview) which provides an API similar to CSS selectors

Comment: this is easily a matter of taste/coding style question, since parameters to select a specific solution are not given

Comment: edited the post: parameters: efficiency, flexibility and possibly aggregation. Something similar to MongoDB or Redis.

Comment: note that the dependencies of minimongo are listed in the projects page, so from this sense it is a rather large codebase to include for this task only

Comment: added jsperf tests for various json-selector libraries, thuis should objectuively answer the efficiency part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#overview) (css-like selectors for json data)?

or [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) (xpath-like API for JSON)

plus if your JSON data/files are very large you may consider some [streaming JSON library](http://oboejs.com/)

**For efficiency** one can check [tests on jsperf](https://www.google.gr/search?q=jsperf+json-select&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=jn8AVbGYMYy3Uc31gfgO) for various json-selector libraries (examples below)

1. [jsperf:json-select](http://jsperf.com/json-select/5)
2. [jspath vs JSONSelect vs jsonpath](http://jsperf.com/jspath-vs-jsonselect/3)
3. One can also [create custom jsperf tests for specific cases](http://jsperf.com/)

**For size**, the various libraries can be measured according to codebase(+dependencies) size

For example, note that the dependencies of minimongo are listed in the projects page, so from this sense it is a rather large codebase to include for this task only.

Then the selection of a library depends on the criteria of efficiency vs size.

A [blog post (2012) on "8 ways to query json structures"](http://orangevolt.blogspot.gr/2012/12/8-ways-to-query-json-structures.html)

1. [JsonSQL](http://www.trentrichardson.com/jsonsql/)
2. [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
3. [jfunk](http://code.google.com/p/jfunk/)
4. [TaffyDB](http://www.taffydb.com/)
5. [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/)
6. [objeq](https://github.com/agilosoftware/objeq)
7. [JsonSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#tryit)
8. [Javascript Array Filtering](http://www.paulfree.com/28/javascript-array-filtering/#more-28)